# What is the red platet floating around my tank

Tags: aquarium, saltwater, snails

Today my wife this red circular think in the tank floating near a snail. Any idea what it is is it some type life or maybe just the snail shedding or whatever they do?[image: Image 2]
[image: Image 1]

Comment: Can you expand on what water conditioning, filtering and tank maintenance you are using?

Comment: @JamesJenkins The salinity is right at 1.026.  I'm using the [AquaTop Canister](http://www.amazon.com/Aquatop-CF400UV-4-Stage-Canister-Filter/dp/B004GJ43EK). Previously I was using a sump but I kept having problem with keeping the water level stable. So it would end up with just air pumping into the tank. I haven't checked the ph or anything in a while but I've never found them out of range. The only problem I have had is maintaining proper salinity. I will check other conditions when I get home. This is a 55g tank